# Linux Security and /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, password-protection

I'm curious to know how the passwords in linux are maintained in /etc/shadow.
Even if you have two users with the same password, the associated entry in /etc/shadow is different.

u1 and u2 have both passwords set to 123

u1:$6$Ht/JdwSZ$no69zCL6q4KYapW2GKPy1iAHl3i.r.0WgvFF5KxF2pzYnG7WfG3.96no2lquIZBFmYJ0VX4VmJoTxErCGOE6c.:15508:0:99999:7:::

u2:$6$7LUQhoQa$V0S7rpjQ7QO1op0EbCpJ7j5B8iRWiKpbQob7axqREqb2q0z6Cs8NxJ1FzzTMNmAysq3ZWqmGjwDpwLZ1CigmB1:15508:0:99999:7:::

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You might try asking at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right. But people in here are smarter.

Comment: @David it would be if he is trying to implement yet another library to read the shadowed passwd. @ DavidJames That's not a valid reason to make an off-topic question and if moderators find this not belonging here your question will get migrated.

Comment: Sure, but that wasn't his question. And DavidJames, please don't intentionally post questions that are off topic.

Comment: This is not off the topic. I'm trying to implement a custom authentication for a project and need a very special way of storing passwords which for sure is not to be discussed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because of *salt*. The second part of an encrypted password field is *salt*, random sequence of characters that is appended to the password during hash calculation.

In your case the *salts* are `Ht/JdwSZ` and `7LUQhoQa`.

Answer (score 0):

Here in Linux two types of file for user authentication one is password and another is shadow file. /etc/password  file contains  user ID’s , group id’s,shell, home directory. That can be ready by the below command.

[root@localhost~]#head  -n  1 /etc/passwd

So it is readable to all. To solve this problem relocating the password to another file that is  /etc/shadow

Since shadow file is encrypted that is why it is almost impossible to hack.

To get more details about Linux system please check below link

http://topicsfeedback.com/linux-password-file/

You also can try below apps in google play store named as "Advance Linux" may be it will be more helpful to get easy access Linux information

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.topicsfeedback.advancelinux